# MySql, Join two neighbor rows

Tags: mysql, join

I am struggling with a simple task in Mysql. I have a table 'Timeline' with

```
ID |   Time   | Task
--------------------- 
1  | 12:00:00 | task1
2  | 12:13:00 | task2
3  | 10:16:00 | task0
```

as  columns. The entries are not ordered by Time. Now I want an output which looks like

```
ID |   From   |  Till    | Task
--------------------------------
3  | 10:16:00 | 12:00:00 | task0
1  | 12:00:00 | 12:13:00 | task1
2  | 12:13:00 |          | task2
```

I guess, this should be quite simple, but I haven't figured it out yet. Looking forward to any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: where does "Till" and "From" came from?

Comment: If you already have the fields you can just add them to your query.  If the fields don't exist already, you'll have to add the columns, and of course, you'll have to populate them when the tasks start and end.  It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  An SQL fiddle would make it easier to answer you .

Comment: To make it more clear. The goal is to have a query, which transforms the first table to the second table. 'From' and 'Till' are using the the Values from the 'Time' column.

Comment: Is it always so that when the next task starts it is automatically the end (till) time of the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
create table tbl(ID int, `Time` time, Task varchar(10));
insert into tbl values
(1, '12:00:00', 'task1'),
(2, '12:13:00', 'task2'),
(3, '10:16:00', 'task0');

select @t := cast(null as time);

select id, task, start, end from (
  select id, @t `end`, @t := `time`, `time` `start`, task from tbl
  order by `time` desc
) a;
```

Comment: @Nussti If answer helped you, you should accept it by checking green mark on the left and optionally upvote :)

Comment: @firedev This is not straightforward, but I'll try to explain: think of each row as loop iteration. In first row, first iteration, we display value of `@t`, which is `null` on first iteration. Then, we assign to `@t` value of `time` in first row (we are still in first iteration). Second iteration: we print value of `@t`, so value of `time` column from first iteration, then we assign value of `time` and so on :)

Comment: Thanks. I've figured you define variables inline after eyeballing it for a while. Neat trick, haven't seen this syntax before!